# Text field focus issue while scrolling the panel in sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, ios6, sencha-touch-2, cordova

I am working on an cordova iOS app(iPad).
I have a form panel inside that i have some sencha fields.
After i set focus on any of the fields as shown below
[image: editing test field]

and scroll the enclosing panel, focus cursor won't scroll, it stays over there only as shown below.

[image: cursor issue]

How can i resolve this problem.

and there is one more observation it happens in ios6 but not in ios5.

Comment: Same thing happens in my app.

Comment: This is the whole problem with web-apps. The only thing you can try is to capture that scroll event and call blur() on the field. This should blur thefield an hide the keyboard, which should prevent this weird stuff from happening. My experience however, is that programmatically executing events in ST2 just isn't working... Your luck is that you're programming for iOS which isnt that bad, i've been working on solutions for this on Android for many days with no result..

Comment: thanks for the comment Rob, I did this(on scroll event calling the blur() on the field) but another problem arises when i want to move the cursor within the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a work around, 
While editing(onFocus) any of the fields i am disabling the scroller of the panel.

```
myPanel.getScrollable().getScroller().setDisabled(true);
```

onBlur of any of the fields enabling the scroller.

```
myPanel.getScrollable().getScroller().setDisabled(false);
```

this wont solve the issue, but solves the purpose.